# Sharing calendars and editing private appointments

Tags: soap, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm confused about sharing calendars and private appointments.

**Step 1:**

- I have shared my calendar with TUser as *editor* (in Outlook).
- I have made private appointment PA1 in my calendar
- I can execute a SOAP call, logged in as TUser, to create a private appointment PA2 in my calendar

**Step 2:**

- I can read both PA1 and PA2 through SOAP calls logged in as TUser
- I can not modify or delete PA1 or PA2 through SOAP calls logged in as TUser
  (I can do so when logged in as myself)

**Step 3:**

- I changed the sharing of my calendar with TUser to level *owner*.
- I still cannot modify or delete PA1 or PA2 through SOAP calls logged in as TUser

**Step 4:**

- I create a private appointment PA3, logged in as TUser (now *owner*), in my calendar
- I cannot modify or delete PA3 through SOAP calls logged in as TUser

**There's some behaviour that I do not understand and I'm wondering if I'm missing something so get this to work**:

> 1) As *editor*, TUser can't modify the private appointments, but it can create them and see everything about them.
>   2) Even as *owner*, TUser can't modify/delete them
>   3) Even when TUser as *owner* creates an event for me, it can't modify/delete it

This is all about `<Sensitivity>Private</Sensitivity>` events, others have no issues.
Running Exchange server 2010 SP3, but accessing it through the SOAP calls as `<typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>`
Error message is always "The specified object was not found in the store"

FWIW, the SOAP calls (without the logins surrounding them):

Create call:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
  xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<soapenv:Header>
  <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
  <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
  <typ:TimeZoneContext>
     <typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
  </typ:TimeZoneContext>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
   <mes:CreateItem SendMeetingInvitations="SendToNone">
   <mes:SavedItemFolderId>
      <typ:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar">
         <typ:Mailbox>
            <typ:EmailAddress>j@t.nl</typ:EmailAddress>
         </typ:Mailbox>
      </typ:DistinguishedFolderId>
   </mes:SavedItemFolderId>
      <mes:Items>
         <typ:CalendarItem>
           <typ:Subject>Prive afspraak Jan aangemaakt door TUser</typ:Subject>
           <typ:Sensitivity>Private</typ:Sensitivity>
           <typ:Body BodyType="Text">Prive afspraak Jan aangemaakt door TUser</typ:Body>
           <typ:ReminderIsSet>false</typ:ReminderIsSet>
           <typ:Start>2014-09-11T17:00:00.000Z</typ:Start>
           <typ:End>2014-09-11T18:00:00.000Z</typ:End>
           <typ:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>Busy</typ:LegacyFreeBusyStatus>
         </typ:CalendarItem>
      </mes:Items>
   </mes:CreateItem>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Update call:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
      <typ:MailboxCulture>en-US</typ:MailboxCulture>
      <typ:TimeZoneContext>
        <typ:TimeZoneDefinition Id="W. Europe Standard Time"/>
      </typ:TimeZoneContext>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:UpdateItem ConflictResolution="AutoResolve" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToNone">
         <mes:ItemChanges>
            <typ:ItemChange>
               <typ:ItemId Id="AAMkADdi[snip]aFAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAA[snip]sYFbe"/>
               <typ:Updates>
                  <typ:SetItemField>
                     <typ:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"/>
                     <typ:CalendarItem>
                       <typ:Subject>Gewijzigd door TUser</typ:Subject>
                     </typ:CalendarItem>
                  </typ:SetItemField>
               </typ:Updates>
            </typ:ItemChange>
         </mes:ItemChanges>
      </mes:UpdateItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is not to **share the calendar folder** but to **grant delegate access** ([This article describes some differences](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/857)).

This is done through `Tools\Options\Delegates'. Here are the Outlook 2007 screenshots where I grant user *TimeTell* delegate access:

[image: Adding a delegate user]

[image: Setting the relevant delegate permissions]

Ticking the *Delegate can see my private items* checkbox is essential. With these settings, my XML code can now also update the private appointments.

Note: If I login to Outlook through a profile for that delegated user Timetell, I can see them but they are just labeled 'Private appointment' and I cannot not open or edit them: 
[image: Timetell user looking at my calendar]

The XML EWS code (like using MAPI) seems to give me more flexibility and [allows me to work around the sensitivity in the reported cases](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7a6de148-b13d-4cfe-ba0e-b9e41fb21b9e/e2010ewssoapsharing-calendars-and-editing-private-appointments?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment).

Comment: I wonder if this is the same in Exchange 2013 and Outlook 2013. If I get a chance to check, I'll report back.

Answer (score 0):

Private items can be seen by a delegate (if the Delegate can see my private items box is checked in Outlook), but only the mailbox owner (and no other, even if you created it) can edit a private appointment - same in Outlook as it is in EWS.

Comment: The weird thing is that private items can *also* be edited/deleted through XML if that box is checked (which is what I want). If I login to Outlook as the delegated user who then tries to edit/delete one of my appointsments, that is not allowed. See my answer to my own question.